# Tabulator, Repeat column at bottom of table

Tags: tabulator

I have a column defined as below

```
{
               title: "Actual",
               field: "actual_fee",
               width: 110,
               hozAlign: "right",
               formatter: "money",
               formatterParams: {
                 decimal: ".",
                 thousand: ",",
                 symbol: "£",
                 precision: 0
               },
               bottomCalc: "sum",
               bottomCalcFormatter: "money",
               bottomCalcFormatterParams: {
                 decimal: ".",
                 thousand: ",",
                 symbol: "£",
                 precision: 0
               }
            },
```

I would like to repeat the column header at the bottom of the table also. Is this possible?

I am  using a bottomCalc, so cannot use a custom formatter to do it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator does not have the option to duplicate the column header, it is only available at the top of the table